# How best to instantiate multiple clone sites and maintain them?

Tags: wordpress, git, deployment, automation, laravel-forge

**Context:**
We have a WordPress/Woocommerce site that has a wide range of custom-tailored features that solve for a specific marketing need.
We want to have variants of this same site (around 80% of the code would be the same) for different domains hosted on completely different servers.

**Question:**
What would be the best approach to instantiate and maintain the clone sites?

**Additional Details**

- We don't track (git) WordPress core files.
- We track (git) only vital plugins for the site, the remaining are ignored.
- The difference between sites would be mainly branding, but still content AND code related.
- The idea is to set up a new "*clone*" site in a short period and still be able to migrate new features in future.

**Deployment Specs**

- We use Laravel Forge to provision AWS servers.
- We use Bash script for installing all dependencies, downloading WP core, restoring a sample DB.
- We use composer for dependency management.

Comment: Laravel Forge???

Comment: Yes, Laravel Forge. It's not for WP, but it's a great tool to provision servers with the full toolkit to manage PHP version, caching, access, and composer of course.

Comment: Yeah I’ve used it for Laravel and I was just making sure that’s what you were talking about before I edited your question.